# WHERE clause is not filtering all specifications

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a query with different specifications in WHERE clause and some of them are being ignored.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.NameLawyer AS 'Comisiona', 
f.Bill As 'Factura', 
f.Amount AS 'Monto_Comisionado', 
f.IdTicket
FROM Bills f 
INNER JOIN Cases i on f.CaseName = i.CaseName
INNER JOIN Payments_received c ON f.IdPRC = c.IdPRC
INNER JOIN Clients cl ON f.IdClient = cl.IdClient
LEFT JOIN type_of_reclaim tr ON tr.id_claim = i.type_of_claim 
WHERE 
/*Search specifications being ignored Client/NameLawyer/IdTicket*/
cl.IdClient =  3 
AND f.NameLawyer = 'FooName'
AND f.IdTicket is null 
/* */
AND month(f.date_payed) = month(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATETIME)) 
/* */
AND YEAR(f.date_payed) = year(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATETIME)) 
/**/
OR month(f.date_payed) IS NULL
/**/
AND f.Date_Bill <= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE))), MONTH(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE))), DAY(EOMONTH((DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE)))))) 
AND
/*BETWEEN*/
 c.Date_Payment_received BETWEEN 
 DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE))), MONTH(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE))), DAY(DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(MM, -3, CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE)))))) 
AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE)), MONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE)), DAY(DATEADD(DAY, 10, EOMONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATE))))) 
/*END BETWEEN*/
```

I guess there's some clause that I'm losing in front of my eyes.

Comment: obviously I am asking why writing `month(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATETIME))`instead of a more simple `9` !

Comment: My assumption is he was using this to troubleshoot why his query wasn't working and normally the date would be a sql parameter. I've done similar when really stuck.

Comment: That `WHERE` looks severely overly complicated... My first suggestion would be take a step back, and think "Do I *really* need all those `DATEFROMPART`s when i could just use a literal date string?"

Comment: @SQLpro Fixed values are variables instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this part in parenthesis

```
AND YEAR(f.date_payed) = year(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATETIME)) 
/**/
OR month(f.date_payed) IS NULL
```

Example

```
(AND YEAR(f.date_payed) = year(CAST('2020-09-14' AS DATETIME)) 
/**/
OR month(f.date_payed) IS NULL)
```

Basically the naked OR is throwing off your results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your intention is with the criteria, but I think your problem is this:

Each record is being evaluated to see if it matches:

```
    cl.IdClient = 3
    AND f.NameLawyer = 'FooName'
    AND f.IdTicket IS NULL
    AND MONTH(f.date_payed) = MONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS datetime))
    AND YEAR(f.date_payed) = YEAR(CAST('2020-09-14' AS datetime))
```

### OR

```
    MONTH(f.date_payed) IS NULL
        /**/
        AND f.Date_Bill <= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                        MONTH(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                        DAY(EOMONTH((DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)))))
                        )
        AND
    /*BETWEEN*/
    c.Date_Payment_received BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                                MONTH(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                                DAY(DATEADD(DAY,
                                                            1,
                                                            EOMONTH(DATEADD(MM, -3, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)))
                                                    )
                                                )
                                    ) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)),
                                                        MONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)),
                                                        DAY(DATEADD(DAY, 10, EOMONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))))
                                        )
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Comisiona           = f.NameLawyer,
        Factura             = f.Bill,
        Monto_Comisionado   = f.Amount,
        f.IdTicket
FROM    Bills                   f
INNER JOIN Cases            i
    ON f.CaseName = i.CaseName
INNER JOIN Payments_received c
    ON f.IdPRC = c.IdPRC
INNER JOIN Clients          cl
    ON f.IdClient = cl.IdClient
LEFT JOIN type_of_reclaim   tr
    ON tr.id_claim = i.type_of_claim
WHERE
    /*Search specifications being ignored Client/NameLawyer/IdTicket*/
    cl.IdClient = 3
    AND f.NameLawyer = 'FooName'
    AND f.IdTicket IS NULL
    /* */
    AND (
            (
                MONTH(f.date_payed) = MONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS datetime))
                AND YEAR(f.date_payed) = YEAR(CAST('2020-09-14' AS datetime))
            )
            OR
            (
                MONTH(f.date_payed) IS NULL
                AND f.Date_Bill <= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                                MONTH(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                                DAY(EOMONTH((DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)))))
                                )
                AND c.Date_Payment_received BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(
                                                        YEAR(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                                        MONTH(DATEADD(MM, -2, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))),
                                                        DAY(DATEADD(DAY,
                                                                    1,
                                                                    EOMONTH(DATEADD(MM, -3, CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)))
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                    ) AND DATEFROMPARTS(
                                                            YEAR(CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)),
                                                            MONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS date)),
                                                            DAY(DATEADD(DAY, 10, EOMONTH(CAST('2020-09-14' AS date))))
                                                        )
            )
    )
```